# Django-filter: How do I determine the current language inside an OrderingFilter?

Tags: django, internationalization, django-filter

I have a django_filter `FilterSet` which contains an `OrderingFilter` as follows:

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language
import django_filters

class geographicEntityFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        ordering = django_filters.OrderingFilter(
                fields = (
                        ('displayedNames__' + get_language()[0:2],'name'),
                )
        )
```

I use that Filter with a class-based view:

```
class GeographicEntityListView(FilterView):
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
                context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
                f = geographicEntityFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
                ...
```

What I want to do is to set the field name depending on the currently selected language by the user. The `get_language()` method always returns "en" no matter what language the site is on. I assume I need to access the language via the `request`, but I can't find any documentation on that.

That works in other parts of my code with other `FilterSets` e.g. when I define a callable for the QuerySet of a `ModelChoiceFilter`, where the `request` is available.

But according to the documentation, the `fields` argument "accepts the ‘list of two-tuples’ syntax ...fields may also just be an iterable of strings". No mention about a callable.

So, any help is appreciated.